# cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:450

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime, google-colaboratory

I was running a python script in colab GPU when I got this error:

> RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute
> at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:450

How can I solve this problem?

Pytorch version: 1.1.0, Cuda version: 9.0.

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your `torch`. I encountered this issue too and after upgrading `torch`, this problem was solved.

I used this command:

```
pip install torch===1.7.1+cu110 torchvision===0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple/
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Bumping an older version in a virtual environment from 1.12.0 to 1.12.1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[You might try using CUDA version 10, instead of 9](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17334#issuecomment-465825827):

> For RTX 2080, you need to use CUDA10, not CUDA 9.2

Answer (score 0):

I updated {torch} to 1.13.1 and cudatoolkit=10.1.243 and the issue was solved.
I'm using RTX-3070

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).